# Laptop turns off immediately while not on charge on ubuntu but stays on windows

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, laptop, battery

I have this weird issue with my MSI GF 65 thin laptop with RTX 3060 graphic card. My laptop works properly with windows without being put on charge but turns off immediately when booting into ubuntu.

Scenario 1:
Laptop has 100% battery, starts the laptop selects windows from bootloader - windows loads shows battery percentage. Turn off laptop and try to load into ubuntu, turns off immediately. Try again, same result. Load back to windows works!

Scenario 2:
Laptop is now connected to a charger, starts windows works, reboot into ubuntu works. Removes the charger while already being logged into ubuntu, laptop doesn't turn off, stays on without charge for about 15 mins and turns off.

The issue I'm facing:

1. Laptop doesn't boot into ubuntu without being connected to a charger, even with 100% charge
2. Battery life on ubuntu is sub par as compared to windows

Please help, ubuntu is my base work environment and it's annoying to have to use a charge every time I want to boot into the system.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS butn it's being happening from before. My machine is a MSI GF 65 thin with Nvidia RTX 3060 6G graphics, I suspect the problem to be the graphic card here.